# How to prepend a software's bin directory to execution path( PATH variable)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, compilation

I am using Ubuntu mounted on a VMWare Workstation Pro. I just installed jdk on the ubuntu and for some project I am working on a mutation testing tool called "major". I downloaded a zipped copy of the software from the website and unzipped it in the HOME directory.

I ran the command `javac -version` and so it displayed me the output (java 1.8.10). But i need the result **javac 1.8.10-Major-v1.3.2** since i want to use ***Major's Compiler and not java compiler*** for compilation of the test results?

I am new to ubuntu so don't know about this. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `cd` to the unzipped directory, and execute the command by `./javac -version`. It is important to include `./` before the command to instruct Ubuntu to find the command in the current directory instead of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: bash: ./javac: No such file or directory

Comment: `cd [unzipped directory]/bin` ? Is it placed inside `bin`? Try list out the directory content by `ls`.

Comment: bin is placed inside the unzipped directory..i mean..major<bin--config--log--etc..

Comment: Which directory are you in when you execute `javac`?

Comment: i'm inside the major directory,  cd major

Comment: `cd major/bin` and then `./javac`, assume `javac` is located inside `major/bin`. In fact, you should check where `javac` is with `ls`.

Comment: You can check the documentation in this [link](http://mutation-testing.org/doc/major.pdf)..hover to 1.1(installation)

Comment: yess..javac is inside the bin directory

Comment: it worked but still the test cases are in other file..so how i am gonna run it? i mean this output is only valid if we are in the directory.! right?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, navigate to the directory where you unzipped the tool, and then type in ./javac -version. The "./" accesses the current directory you are in. Alternatively, you could do "/home/name_of_directory_with_tool/javac -version".

If you want to use this compiler by default (instead of the normal java compiler), you can add the location of it to your PATH variable. Assuming that the binary "javac" program is in a folder named "tool" in your "home" directory (with a path of /home/tool/javac), then enter the following command in your terminal:

```
export PATH=/home/tool:$PATH
```

This command will prepend /home/tool to your PATH variable such that the shell checks there first. Don't worry, its not permanent. Make a new shell, or restart Ubuntu if you want your old PATH back. If you want to make this change permanent (modify your PATH upon every startup), you can add that command to the end of your ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: should i prepend the bin folder or the complete folder..because i export the path..and then ran the command., but I'm getting the same output for java compiler and not for major

Comment: export PATH=/home/major/bin:$PATH ?? OR export PATH=/home/major:$PATH..actually i did both but still im getting the same output

Comment: after export, what is the value of PATH environment, i.e., the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: /home/major/bin/javac:/home/tusshar/bin:/home/tusshar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: The PATH environment is used to point to the directory that your command  is in, but directly pointing to the command itself. So, the command `export PATH=/home/major/bin:$PATH` is good enough. No need to point to `/home/major/bin/javac`

Comment: I am still getting the same class path..but not the version of the compiler as the output!

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the directory of your major javac compiler and executing it directly? i.e. `./javac  `? Does that work?